# Non Jquery - Show div if dropdown option selected

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm adding a custom woocommerce dropdown meta in my backend product edit page via function in my functions.php :

```
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {
  global $woocommerce, $post;
  echo '<div class="options_group">';

  // Select Dropdown Workshop Available
  woocommerce_wp_select( 
  array( 
      'id'      => '_wc_workshop', 
      'label'   => __( 'Workshop Available', 'woocommerce' ), 
      'options' => array(
      'one'   => __( 'Not Available', 'woocommerce' ),
      'two' => __( 'Workshop Available', 'woocommerce' )
        )
    )
  );

  echo '</div>';    
}
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

    // Dropdown Inspection Available - Save Data
    $woocommerce_select = $_POST['_wc_workshop'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_select ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_workshop', esc_attr( $woocommerce_select ) );
}
?>
```

This works great, new meta is added and is correctly saving data.

In my product template page, I have a `div` that I would like to show based on the dropdown selection. So IF the option TWO ( Workshop Available ) is chosen from the dropdown, I'd like to show :

```
<div class="special-conditions-icons">
    <img src="http://...../icons/workshop-available.png" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:0" />   
</div>
```

I am trying to experiment with the following:

```
<?php 
$workshop_array = array( 'Workshop Available' );
$workshop_class = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], '_wc_workshop' );
   if( in_array( $workshop_class[0]->slug, $workshop_array )) { 
?>
       <div class="special-conditions-icons">
              <img src="http://...../icons/workshop-available.png" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:0" /> 
           </div>
<?php } ?>
```

But I'm just not getting anywhere with this code.

I am trying to avoid using Jquery. I just don't know how to use it properly in the template files as they all start with `<?php` and don't have the html header.

Comment: i'm not familiar with wordpress but [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) seems to indicate `->slug` would get you a string? why not just make your if statement: `if($workshop_class[0]->slug === 'Workshop Available') {...`?

Comment: and if the previous comment is mistaken in its assumption, what *does* `$workshop_class[0]->slug` get you?

Comment: if i am reading you correctly, you want to show the div when the dropdown is selected rather than on page load decide if to show? You need js (jquery). You can actually put js anywhere in a php template file , close the php tag and insert as normal inside script tags.

Comment: @David but then I need to call the JS library in the header, correct ? How do I go about it if the template doesn't have any `<head>` tags ?

Comment: you could load jquery anywhere outside the head as well, but wp lets you enqueue from your functions.php file, `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script for the correct hook to add it to).

Comment: Did you try to `var_dump` your variables?

Comment: @David David, i think I'll give this Jquery a go .. new to this and been trying to avoid it, so it's all just a little confusing. Would you be able to post an example of the code that could be inserted in my code above? Many thanks

Comment: @brasofilo I haven't tried the `var_dump` yet, no .. how could I go about this ?

Comment: i see someone has posted an js answer below, but try it yourself as well, its the best way to learn how to interact with the dom, js is actually more straight forward than jquery and doesn't require you to load in a library and there are loads of examples on this site as well.

Comment: @David will give it a go, many thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved - NO JQUERY or JS necessary, but many thanks for taking your time to try and help.

The lines are as follows:

```
<?php 
$value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wc_workshop', true);
            if($value == 'two') {
?>
       <div class="special-conditions-icons">
              <img src="http://...../icons/workshop-available.png" style="width:32px; height:32px; border:0" /> 
           </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comment you can load jquery anywhere in your page `head` or `body` but must be before the closing `</body>` tag, however using raw JavaScript : [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/eyqsahkb/2/),

```js
var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById('hiddenDiv'),
    select = document.getElementById('slct');

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
 hiddenDiv.style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
#hiddenDiv{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
select:
<select id="slct">
    <option></option>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
    <option>option 4</option>
</select>
<hr>
<div id="hiddenDiv">
 I was hidden before you select from the dropdown
</div>
```